# Copy Delta tables from ADB to Azure SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I a trying to copy multiple delta tables from ADB to Azure SQL server via ADB notebook.
One of my Delta table size is 11 GB but when it is copied in SQL server it's size is 99 GB.

I have matched the count of same table present in ADB and SQL server(After succesfuly coping)..Count is same. only size has increased.

How is it possible?

I have few questions:-

1. when copying the delta tables from ADB to Azure SQL, will the size of table copied in Azure SQL , increases? Decreases? or remains same?
2. if increases then how to reduce the size of table in Azure SQL server after coping from delta table ADB

Comment: Delta stores files using snappy or gzip compression

Comment: can you share any link that supports saying that delta tables are compressed

Comment: Cannot find a link. Probably, compression is not Delta lake feature but feature of parquet format which is used by Delta lake. When you list files in your Delta table then their name may include `...snappy...` or `...gzip...` inside the name - it indicates what format was used to compress the file.

Answer (score 0):

Delta tables are columnar and compressed. When coping to SQL server data will be decompressed, so size on SQL will almost always increase.

To decrease size of SQL table you can use:

1. Data compression, which compress table data at the row or page level - See details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver16
2. Column store index - which turns the table to columnar base and has a better compression rate - See details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: can you share any link which supports saying that delta tables are compressed and while coping into SQL data will get decompressed

Comment: @KishanRaj , Hope this help - https://delta.io/blog/delta-lake-vs-parquet-comparison/#:~:text=It's%20quick%20to%20read%20the,the%20entire%20table%20is%20slow.